# Controlar excepción de HttpHandler

Tags: android, json, api, rest

Estaba realizando una aplicación que se conecta a un servidor para obtener un json, el cual mostrará en un listview. 
La aplicación me funciona correctamente, pero me gustaría saber como puedo controlar el error que devuelve el método doInBackground si el servidor no está disponible por el motivo que sea. Lo he intendado con un try pero cuando lleva un rato intentando conectarse al servidor la apliación se cierra

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        HttpHandler hh = new HttpHandler();

        String infoObtenida=null;

        //Solicito el listado de información al servidor
        try{
            infoObtenida = hh.SolicitarNoticias(ruta);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (infoObtenida != null) {
            try {
                //Cogemos el objeto json
                JSONObject objetoJSON = new JSONObject(infoObtenida);

                //Cogemos la infomación de cada noticia
                JSONArray noticias = objetoJSON.getJSONArray("noticia");

                //Recorremos cada una de las noticias y la añadimos a la coleccion
                for (int i = 0; i < noticias.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject n = noticias.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = n.getInt("id");
                    String titulo = n.getString("titulo");
                    String imagen = n.getString("imagen");
                    String texto = n.getString("texto");


                    //Añado cada noticia a la coleccion
                    todasNoticias.add(new Noticia(id,titulo,imagen,texto));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No se puede obtener la información del servidor, posiblemente el servidor esté caido",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

----Método SolicitarNoticias

```
    public String SolicitarNoticias(String ruta) {
    String respuesta = null;

    try {
        //Conectamos con el servidor
        URL url = new URL(ruta);
        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //Leemos la respuesta del servidor, y la almacenamos en formato texto en una variable
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
        respuesta=transformarFlujoACadena(is);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return respuesta;
}
```

-- Logcat
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Antonio, es importante agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat para definir una solución. Te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio y revisar [ask], saludos!

Comment: La clase   HttpHandler extiende de Handler? si es así no es necesario crear un handler para realizar una petición.

Comment: La clase HttpHandler no extiende de Handler